# ActiveMQ Queues Deletion

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I've copied an ActiveMQ 5.13.3 Server Virtual Machine from our production environment to our integration environment.  When I start the new integration ActiveMQ server I see all of the queues that were present in Production.  Obviously there is some local file persisted with this information.  What file do I delete to remove these queues?  After that I will start my Producers/Consumers to re-create the queues.

Comment: apache-activemq-5.13.3

Comment: I just searched in another post that if I delete $APACHE_BASE/data/kahadb/*.log files will remove the queues?

Answer (score 0):

By default dynamically created destinations and message data is stored in the ActiveMQ `data` directory. If you stop the broker, remove that directory, and restart the broker all the previously dynamically created destinations (and their messages) will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Determined that I needed to move all of the files out of $APACHE_BASE/data/kahadb/ directory and restart.